# Automate a process using bash script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have a unimrcp client process (ucp) and I want to spawn multiple ucp using shell script.

Whenever I spawn a ucp, it returns a command line using which I can access different functionalities in ucp. So I want to write a script that achieves following,

1. Spawn a ucp process
2. wait until the ucp's command line appears
3. access ucp's functionality with a command "run recog"

Note that ./ucp && run recog does not work since ./ucp is finished only after we exit from the command line of ucp.

I tried the following for this,

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
./ucp &                                                               
fg                                                                              
echo "run recog uni2"                                                           
wait
```

However, `./ucp &` results into starting the client process and then writing "?????" on the client console resulting into "????" command not found. Following are the logs,

```
./script.sh

2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Set Property ip:127.0.0.1
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMU]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMA]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [L16]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechsynth]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechrecog]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620588 [NOTICE] Register Resource [recorder]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620588 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speakverify]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620593 [INFO]   Register Resource Factory
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create SofiaSIP Agent [SIP-Agent-1] [1.12.11-227-g73efc97] sip:127.0.0.1:8062;transport=udp
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [SIP-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create RTSP Client [RTSP-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [RTSP-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create MRCPv2 Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Connection Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create Media Engine [Media-Engine-1]
unknown command: ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Is this the right way to achieve what I mentioned in the question? (spawn a client and run a command on its console)? If yes, why does the "./ucp &" results in reading "?????" considering that as input to its console? Note that this does not happen if I simply fire "./ucp & fg " from the console. It can see the expected behavior of the command when I do it from the console. The issue appears when I try to execute the script.

If this is not a right way, How can I achieve what I mentioned in the question? (1, 2, and 3)

Thank you

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310)

Comment: Okay. I will delete the question from the other site. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to send input to the stdin of a background process. One way to do this would be to use a named pipe.

```
# Create a named pipe
mkfifo /tmp/ucp-input

# Run the background service using the named pipe as stdin
cat /tmp/ucp-input | ./ucp &

# Echo commands to the named pipe to send them to the service's stdin
echo "run recog uni2" > /tmp/ucp-input
```

I've tested this with a simple Bash script that just echoes back the input and it appears to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a really interesting solution. However, it got stuck into cat /tmp/ucp-input | ./ucp & part runs into the same issue I mentioned in the question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477612/automate-a-process-using-bash-script has a solution to that particular problem. But I like your solution. It's neat. Let me see if the issue mentioned in the question can be handled. Thanks again